# recovery of parameter from nodejs express impossible

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, get, postman

good evening everyone
i am trying to set up an express server with mongodb
as long as I define routes without parameters my tests with postman work, but as soon as I create a get route with parameters, I have a **404 error Cannot GET /api/stuff**
I put a console.log on this route and it does not pass
I've been looking for hours and trying several solutions without result
here are my codes could you help me to solve and understand the problem
thank you to all of you

my file server.js :

```
     const http = require('http');
     const app = require('./app');

     const normalizePort = val => {
     const port = parseInt(val, 10);

     if (isNaN(port)) {
       return val;
     }
     if (port >= 0) {
       return port;
     }
     return false;
   };
   const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4000');
   app.set('port', port);

   const errorHandler = error => {
     if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
       throw error;
     }
     const address = server.address();
     const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port: ' + port;
     switch (error.code) {
       case 'EACCES':
         console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges.');
         process.exit(1);
         break;
       case 'EADDRINUSE':
         console.error(bind + ' is already in use.');
         process.exit(1);
         break;
       default:
         throw error;
     }
   };

   const server = http.createServer(app);

   server.on('error', errorHandler);
   server.on('listening', () => {
     const address = server.address();
     const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port ' + port;
     console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
   });

   server.listen(port);
```

my file app.js

````
const express = require('express');
// Pour gérer la demande POST provenant de l'application front-end, 
// nous devrons être capables d'extraire l'objet JSON de la demande. Il nous faudra le package body-parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// utilisation du package mongoose pour interagir avec MongoDb
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import du schema de donnees Users
const User = require('./models/user');

const path = require ('path');


const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user1:bz8FcivTvhnjxzog@cluster0.d3kne.mongodb.net/leads_manager?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  { useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB réussie !'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB échouée !'));


// éfinissez sa fonction json comme middleware global pour votre application, 
// juste après avoir défini les headers de la réponse :
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true,
    }),
  );

  
app.use (cors({
    origin: "*", // restrict calls to those this address
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE' 
  }))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

//   recupere un utilisateur
app.get('/api/stuff/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(
        'coucou'
    );
    
  });


  

module.exports = app;```

thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Make your route parameter optional since when you add `:id` in route now its mandatory for you to pass something for it. Example `/api/stuff/someid2131`. To make it run for both `/api/stuff` and `/api/stuff/someid2131` change your route to this `/api/stuff/:id?`.

Question `:id?` tells that your route is optional.